# Java: Misspell reporter using regex (how to parse for misspells)

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, parsing

I am creating a program that parses strings to report instances of misspells. I want it to report multiple instances opposed to one single variable. I had it interpret user input for instance;

> GOOGGOUGGUIG

and take that string and report all instances where "GO" was spelled incorrectly 4 times because as seen in the above user entry we have "OG", "UG", "GU" and "IG".

So my result should be

> Y was spelled incorrectly x/count times.

I don't care about the pattern reversal portion. I only used it to find instances for when I used the single variable.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class misspellReporter
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      String singleString = "";
      System.out.println("Enter text here");
      singleString = keyboard.nextLine();

          String str = singleString;
          //String strToSearch = "OG"; //I used this at first
          String[] strToSearch = {"GU", "UG", "IG", "GI"}; //I want to use this array instead
          String strToSearchReversed = new StringBuffer(strToSearch).reverse().toString();
          Pattern strPattern = Pattern.compile(strToSearchReversed);
          Matcher matcher = strPattern.matcher(str);
          int counter = 0;
          while(matcher.find()) {
              ++counter;
          }

      System.out.println(strToSearch+" was spelt as "+strToSearchReversed+" "+counter+" times");
  }
}
```

Thank you ahead of time! The reason this question is different for me is because I haven't seen anyone else on the forum parse with matcher and patterns. I've used other methods but this one has a specific action to it that I take an interest in.

Comment: This sounds like a contrived theoretical problem or an interview question, not an actual problem.  Because in the input GOOGGOUGGUIG, OO is also a mispelling, GG is also a mispelling, etc.

Comment: I know but the purpose is that I want it to only take the listed variables, i.e. the ones I have listed in that array in my snippet

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: you have to comment out the line with the array and uncomment "//String strToSearch = "OG";"

Comment: Ha, ha. Then - using GOOGGOUGGUIG as input - it prints `OG was spelt as GO 2 times.` What should it print?

Comment: I want it to take more assignments rather than just OG

Comment: You have made a mess out of the code.

Comment: I know there are compile errors everywhere

Comment: You take the code I posted, not some random stuff.

Comment: But the program must be able to take user entry and then parse it for strings like UG, IG, GU... etc.

Comment: You have the code for reading lines from standard input in Lab6.java. Use that, call the method and print whatever you want to have printed.

Comment: Can you edit the text on https://ideone.com/KjDkak to show me what you have done please?

Comment: I'm telling you, if you're getting this to work, you must have something completely different from what I have

Comment: It cannot find symbol for nucleotide.length `for( int i = 0; i < nucleotide.length; i += 2 ){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for many substrings at the same time using a regex composed like this:

```
public class MatchPairs {
    private static final String[] strs = {"GU", "UG", "IG", "GI"};
    public static int matches( String str ){
        String strToSearch = String.join( "|", strs );
        Pattern strPattern = Pattern.compile(strToSearch);
        Matcher matcher = strPattern.matcher(str);
        int counter = 0;
        while(matcher.find()) {
             ++counter;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

You can save yourself the trouble of adding the reversed substrings by reversing the composition and appending it after another `|`.
Output:

```
 GOOGGOUGGUIG was spelt as GU|UG|IG|GI 3 times
```

To avoid overlapping matches, set the start offset:

```
public class MatchNoOverlap {
    private static final String[] strs = {"GU", "UG", "IG", "GI"};
    public static int matches( String str ){
        String strToSearch = String.join( "|", strs );
        Pattern strPattern = Pattern.compile(strToSearch);
        Matcher matcher = strPattern.matcher(str);
        int counter = 0;
        int start = 0;
        while(matcher.find(start)) {
            ++counter;
            start = matcher.start() + 2;
        }
        return counter;
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        System.out.println( matches( "GOOGGOUGGUGIGI" ) );
    }
}
```

**Later**

```
/* Counts the number of contiguous stretches of non-valid pairs between
 * contiguous stretches of valid pairs
 */
private static final String[] valids = 
    {"AT", "TA", "AA", "TT", "CG", "GC", "CC", "GG"};

public static int mismatches( String str ){
    String strToSearch = "(?:(?:..)*?)((?:" + String.join( "|", valids) + ")+)";
    Pattern strPattern = Pattern.compile( strToSearch);
    Matcher matcher = strPattern.matcher(str);
    int counter = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    while(matcher.find( start )){
        int s = matcher.start(1);
        end = matcher.end(1);
        if( s > start ){
            ++counter;
            // System.out.println( "s>Start "  + s );
        }
        // System.out.println( "match:" + matcher.group() +  " s=" + s );
        start = matcher.end();
    }
    if( end < str.length() ){
        ++counter;
        // System.out.println( "end< length" );
    }
    return counter;
}
```

**Or, counting each "bad pair":

```
public static int badPairs( String str ){
    String strToSearch = "(?:(?:..)*?)((?:" + String.join( "|", valids) + ")+)";
    Pattern strPattern = Pattern.compile( strToSearch);
    Matcher matcher = strPattern.matcher(str);
    int counter = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    while(matcher.find( start )){
        int s = matcher.start(1);
        end = matcher.end(1);
        counter += s - start;
        start = matcher.end();
    }
    counter += str.length() - end;
    return counter/2;
}
```

**Without regex**

```
public static int valid( String str ){
    Set<String> valset = new HashSet<>();
    for( String s: valids ) valset.add( s );
    int validCount = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2 ){
        if( valset.contains( str.substring( i, i+2 ) ) ) validCount++;
    }
    return validCount;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72048/discussion-on-answer-by-laune-java-misspell-reporter-using-regex-how-to-parse).